# Calling a user defined Jquery function with the $(this) selector

Tags: jquery, this

I am trying to make a function to hide the circle when it is clicked on.

I think my syntax is right but nothing happens when i click on the circle.

I have the following code:

```js
function Disappearing() {
  $(this).hide();
}

$(".circle").click(function() {
  Disappearing();
})
```

```css
.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="red" class="circle"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Disappearing()` can not access clicked object unless you passed it to that function, in the other words `this` point to current object in event function, so you should get `$(this)` in `click` event and then pass it to `Disappearing()` .

try this:

```js
function Disappearing (circle) {
   circle.hide();
}
      
$(".circle").click(function() {
 Disappearing($(this));  
});
```

```css
.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
#red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="red" class="circle"></div>
```

Comment: `$(circle).hide();` really should be `circle.hide();` - no need to convert it to a jquery object again

Comment: Thanks, `Should be` or `Can be` ?

Comment: both I suppose. Because `$(this)` is already a jquery object, which has the `.hide` method, so you don't need to make it an object again by using `$(circle)`

Comment: Appreciate for advise, but both of them get working in little different, you mean by `$(el)` in that function JQuery need find it again and do one step more.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the scope to your function using a parmameter

```js
function Disappearing(el) {
  $(el).hide()
}

$(".circle").click(function() {
  Disappearing(this)
})
```

```css
.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="red" class="circle"></div>
```